# How tags associated to users are chosen?

Tags: support, users

I was looking at [User](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users) main page and I saw that there is a set of three tags associated to each user name. I am wondering how these tags are chosen, how does the algorithm work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think** These are the three tags that the user has generated the most rep from.

For instance, my own list of [die2nite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/die2nite),[xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360), & [xbox-live-arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live-arcade) are the tags that I have earned the most rep relating to.  Here is an image that should give you a better understanding of what that means:

---

[image: Die2niteReps]

This is a breakdown of my rep-gain from the [die2nite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/die2nite) tag.

Comment: Die2Nite doesn't have spaces/dashes in it...

Comment: @Ullallulloo You're absolutely correct.  :)

Comment: Close, but it appears to be rep from *Answers*, not *Questions*. At least on my tags, it took glass="answered 1 non-wiki question for 9 rep" over redstone="asked 2 non-wiki questions for 6 rep, answered 2 non-wiki questions for 9 rep". (with alphabetical order taking glass first as they both had 9 answer-rep).

Comment: Then again, it could be *random* or time-based :) I just looked at your tags, @GnomeSlice - and they were *Minecraft, game-mechanics, Halo-2*. Of which *game-mechanics* shows zero rep for answers.